# Popup window is displayed with a space/gap on immersive mode, on Marshmallow only

Tags: android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

Specifically on Marshmallow (tested on Nexus 5X and 6P) when I open a `PopupWindow` (which has match_parent width and height) over a screen in immersive mode, the content of the popup doesn't expand to full screen, there's a gap where the navigation buttons used to be. The effect is as if invisible navigation buttons were still there, adding a space/gap/margin.

This is how I create the popup:

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, false);

popup.showAtLocation(activity.findViewById(R.id.full_screen_root_view), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

This is the beginning of the popup layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#AA000000">
```

This is the full screen view where the popup is displayed:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/full_screen_root_view"
    android:background="@android:color/black">
```

Do you know if anything changed with Marshmallow that would cause this bug specifically? All works well in a Nexus 5, with version 5.0.1 and other older phones/versions I tested. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot with that behavior?

Comment: It’s been a while I created this post and I don’t have a screen shot anymore. At the time I ended up not using a a `PopupWindow` because of this issue. Instead I had a `View` in the xml layout and animated it disappearing and appearing for a nice visual effect.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem before. I solved by setting PopupWindow focusable to false before is show.

```
PopupWindow mWindow = new PopupWindow(context);
mWindow.setFocusable(false);
mWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

set popup window background drawable.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE);
setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL

```
popup.showAtLocation(activity.findViewById(R.id.full_screen_root_view), Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
```